# Execution time of spawned processes increase after weeks

Tags: c#

I have a curious problem with increasing execution time when I create processes with `System.Diagnostics.Process()`. I have a “parent” console application which periodically (every few seconds) creates other “child” console applications. The child processes do some work (which takes a few hundred milliseconds) and exits.
Everything runs fine for about 4-12 weeks. Then, the execution time of the child processes begin to increase slowly. A few weeks later the execution times have doubled or tripled and more and more often the child processes are killed by the parent application which monitors the child execution time by `Process.WaitForExit(TimeOutValue)`.
I now stop and restart the “parent” application. After that, the execution time of the child processes is normal as at the beginning.
I monitored all performance counters of the “parent” application. However there is no counter which increases. I cannot understand how the “parent” application can have such an impact to the execution time of the “child” applications. In the code below I have stripped away unnecessary parts to focus to the problem. Have anyone an idea what is going wrong here?
 OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

The **Parent** application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Bss.CheckExecTimeScheduler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Arg0 = "Bss.CheckTask.exe";
            string Args = "";
            int WaitForExit = 2000;

            int NumOfTimeOuts = 0;
            int NumOfNormalExits = 0;
            int NumOfExceptions = 0;
            long MinExecTime = 100000;
            long MaxExecTime = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Press 'r' for a report ...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 's' to start/stop execution ...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit ...");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

                    cki = Console.ReadKey();

                    if (cki.KeyChar == 'q')
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (cki.KeyChar == 'r')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("Normal Exits: " + NumOfNormalExits.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Timeouts    : " + NumOfTimeOuts.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Exceptions  : " + NumOfExceptions.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Minimum execution time [ms]: " + MinExecTime.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Maximum execution time [ms]: " + MaxExecTime.ToString());
                    }
                    if (cki.KeyChar == 's')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Execution stopped. Press 's' to resume...");
                        while (true)
                        {
                            cki = Console.ReadKey();
                            if (cki.KeyChar == 's')
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Execution resumed...");
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Illegal key. Execution stopped. Press 's' to resume...");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                try
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Arg0, Args);
                    procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                    proc.Start();
                    //AddMsg("Message: Command Thread launched. Arg0 = " + Arg0 + "; Args = " + Args + "; ProcessId = " + proc.Id.ToString());

                    if (proc.WaitForExit(WaitForExit) == false)
                    {
                        if (!proc.HasExited)
                        {
                            proc.Kill();
                            NumOfTimeOuts++;
                            AddExecTime("-1");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            long elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                            NumOfNormalExits++;
                            if (elapsed < MinExecTime) MinExecTime = elapsed;
                            if (elapsed > MaxExecTime) MaxExecTime = elapsed;
                            AddExecTime(elapsed.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        long elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                        NumOfNormalExits++;
                        if (elapsed < MinExecTime) MinExecTime = elapsed;
                        if (elapsed > MaxExecTime) MaxExecTime = elapsed;
                        AddExecTime(elapsed.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    NumOfExceptions++;
                    AddMsg("Exception catched: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void AddExecTime(string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + "Bss.CheckExecTimeScheduler.ExecTimes.txt");
                streamWriter.WriteLine(msg);
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing ExecTimes: Exception catched: " + e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff ") + msg);
            }
        }

        public static void AddMsg(string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + "Bss.CheckExecTimeScheduler.Logfile.txt");
                streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff ") + msg);
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing logfile: Exception catched: " + e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff ") + msg);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The **Child** application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Bss.CheckTask
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

            long elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            try
            {
                StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + "Bss.CheckTask.ExecTimes.txt");
                streamWriter.WriteLine(elapsed.ToString());
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing Bss.CheckTask.ExecTimes.txt: Exception catched: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know if that can cause this kind of problem, but I noticed that you are not disposing the `System.Diagnostics.Process` after you've been using it. Have you tried to simply wrap it in a `using` clause so that it is properly disposed?

Answer (score 0):

I have run the above example on  a virtual machine (Win7 prof. 64bit, 4Gb RAM, Xeon at 2.27Ghz). After about 4 hours (this is about 88000 Samples) running I can see that the execution time (as seen from the process which creates the child process) increase slowly.

[Execution time chart parent view without using block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcI64.png)

However from the view of the child process the execution time seems not to change:

I then enclosed the creation of `System.Diagnotics.Process()` in a using block as proposed by bassfader. And I allowed the child process to run 4000ms (instead of 2000ms) before it is killed by the parent process. Now it takes about 30 hours (this means about 550000 samples) until the execution times start to increase:

[Execution time chart parent view with using block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fsP9.png)

again the execution time as seen from the child process seems not to change (I wanted to upload these charts but I am only allowed to append 2 Pictures here)

The using block seems to improve the situation. However there is still a loss of resources. Anybody an idea what happens here or what i can do in my code to avoid the increasing execution time?